# Redirect a user to their previous location after a successful oAuth2 callback: how?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

We have an app which which has various different pages which require authentication; this auth uses Google's oAuth2 flow and is currently working correctly apart from one thing: after we receive the callback from Google at our callback endpoint, we have no way of knowing where to redirect the user after success as we have no idea which page they were on when they first started the auth process.

What happens instead is that we redirect to the same page for all successful requests; this is jarring to the user as they've likely landed on a page they did not request and have to navigate back to the section they desired.

I can't find anybody talking about how to do this and all the Google samples simply do what we do and redirect the user to a standard URL.

We've tried url-encoding the redirect we want as a query parameter on the callback URL we pass to Google initially but this fails as the URL no longer exactly matches the 'allowed' one we have set up in the Google APIs console (and there is only one box to add one).

Obviously our callback method would check any data returned from them before redirecting the user (i.e make sure it's a valid place to redirect the user to) - so, is there any safe way of doing this? Ideally without having to put the URL on the session..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The official technique is to set the state parameter which is returned to the callback url

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your user to a page with a javascript function to read in the localcache the last url visited before authentication.
You can also use a cookies for that.
This solution can be coupled with a breadcrumb widget on your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the fromUrl into the memcache and redirect on this url when you OAuth workflow is completed.
If the memcache value has been unset, redirect to the home page.